# Logger Instance Changing with Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, log4j

I have written below code to process requests using multi threading. Here ConnectorRunner is a runnable object-

```
        for (String request : requests) {   
            propLog.put("log4j.appender.reqIdLog.File", request.getRequestId().concat(".log")); // Setting request fle appender to write on file named with current request id
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(propLog);
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("reqIdLogger");    // Creating logger for the current requst here

            ConnectorRunner connectorRunner = null;
            try {
                connectorRunner = new ConnectorRunner(request, logger);

                // setting some other fields here

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            executorService.execute(connectorRunner);
        }
```

In ConnectorRunner class I am writing some execution logs. I want to write logs in such a way that all the logs for a particular request goes to a log file named with the request id for that request. To achieve this, I am creating a new logger instance for every request in every iteration and setting the file appender to write logs on a file named with request id and passing it to ConnectorRunner constructor.

The problem I am facing is, logs of all the threads (all the requests) are getting written to a log file that belongs to last thread(thread executed last). I am not sure what's going wrong here as I am creating a new ConnectorRunner object every time and creating a new logger instance for every thread.

Any help/guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you define a Logger inside your `ConnectorRunner` instead of passing it as argument? And regarding your last sentence, `...and creating a new logger instance for every thread.`, that's not true: please see [`Logger.getLogger(String name)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html#getLogger(java.lang.String)).

Comment: **No. Just No!** This is assuming a huge number of things, most of which are not true. For example `PropertyConfigurator.configure` cannot be called from multiple threads. You need to use a sifting appender and MDC.

Comment: `getLogger` looks a logger by name. Once it is created you keep getting the same Logger.  Logging is expensive enough as it is but a file per request will make it slower, and possibly give you a very large number of files.